# the order of execution of functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

During studying node.js I am faced with an example that produces strange results. Here's the code:

```
/* 01 */  var zlib = require("zlib");
/* 02 */  var input = '...............text...............';
/* 03 */  zlib.deflate(input, function(err, buffer) {
/* 04 */    if (!err) {
/* 05 */      console.log("deflate (%s): ", buffer.length,buffer.toString('base64'));
/* 06 */      zlib.inflate(buffer, function(err, buffer) {
/* 07 */        if (!err) {
/* 08 */          console.log("inflate (%s): ", buffer.length, buffer.toString());
/* 09 */        }
/* 10 */      });
/* 11 */      zlib.unzip(buffer, function(err, buffer) {
/* 12 */        if (!err) {
/* 13 */          console.log("unzip deflate (%s): ", buffer.length, buffer.toString());
/* 14 */        }
/* 15 */      });
/* 16 */    }
/* 17 */  });
/* 18 */ 
/* 19 */  zlib.deflateRaw(input, function(err, buffer) {
/* 20 */    if (!err) {
/* 21 */      console.log("deflateRaw (%s): ", buffer.length, buffer.toString('base64'));
/* 22 */      zlib.inflateRaw(buffer, function(err, buffer) {
/* 23 */        if (!err) {
/* 24 */          console.log("inflateRaw (%s): ", buffer.length, buffer.toString());
/* 25 */        }
/* 26 */      });
/* 27 */    }
/* 28 */  });
/* 29 */ 
/* 30 */  zlib.gzip(input, function(err, buffer) {
/* 31 */    if (!err) {
/* 32 */      console.log("gzip (%s): ", buffer.length, buffer.toString('base64'));
/* 33 */      zlib.gunzip(buffer, function(err, buffer) {
/* 34 */        if (!err) {
/* 35 */          console.log("gunzip (%s): ", buffer.length, buffer.toString());
/* 36 */        }
/* 37 */      });
/* 38 */      zlib.unzip(buffer, function(err, buffer) {
/* 39 */        if (!err) {
/* 40 */          console.log("unzip gzip (%s): ", buffer.length, buffer.toString());
/* 41 */        }
/* 42 */      });
/* 43 */    }
/* 44 */  });
```

I would expect that following results be produced :

```
deflate (18) : ...some thing strange !... 
inflate (34) :............text.............
unzip deflate (34) :............text.............
deflateRaw (12) :...some thing strange !... 
inflateRaw34() :............text.............
gzip (30) :...some thing strange !... 
gunzip(34) :............text.............
unzip gzip (34) :............text.............
```

but I encountered this:

[image: actual execution order]

So what's the order of execution of functions if it's not according to the order they are called?

Comment: Async function doesn't wait until its callback is called. It doesn't block the execution process. The flow you're getting is right. To ensure things go exactly in order you need, either put them inside callback functions, or use async/await.

Comment: Which means, on top level, you will only have `zlib.deflate` call, and then hellish spaghetti of consecutive callbacks, one per each function call and each containing a single call in it.

Comment: Functions are always executed in the order they are called. Calling a function means executing it. You are confused about when functions are called, and that is very often not the order they are written down.

Comment: + Rishat Muhametshin
you mean the order of calls is as I wrote but the order of completion is as image?for example inflate is called before deflateRaw but is completed before it?
and this may be due to the more intensity of the decompressing tasks?
is that right?